# c++ array[var][2] as a class member

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, allocation

I would like to have an array of unsigned integers within a class, and its size should be [var][2], so the user will be able to choose var in runtime.
Is there a better way than allocating a two dimensional array (an allocated array of pointers to allocated arrays)?

In the class I have:

```
unsigned int *(*hashFunc);
```

And in the initializing function:

```
hashFunc = new unsigned int*[var];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<var; ++i)
    hashFunc[i] = new unsigned int[2];
```

I want to only allocate once, and I think it should somehow be possible because I only have one unknown dimension (var is unknown but 2 I know from the beginning).

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? This is the valid way to do this. In any event, you may want to try an `std::vector` if you are unhappy with `new/delete`

Comment: It's just that what AndreyT offered is much better and I thought there should be something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To answer the direct question.) You can declare the pointer as

```
int (*hashFunc)[2];
```

and allocate it in one shot as

```
hashFunc = new int[var][2];
```

Answer (score 3):

If the sizes are known at compilation time, you should use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). If one of the dimensions are not known until runtime, you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

You can of course combine them:

```
std::vector<std::array<unsigned int, 2>> hashFunc;
```

The above declares `hashFunc` to be a vector of arrays, and the arrays is of size two and of type `unsigned int`, just like specified in the question.

Then to add a new inner array just use [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) of the vector:

```
hashFunc.push_back({{ 1, 2 }});
```

(And yes, double braces are needed. The outer to construct the `std::array` object, and the inner for the actual array data.)

Or if you want to set the size of the outer vector at once (for example if you (runtime) know the size beforehand) you could do e.g.

```
hashFunc = std::vector<std::array<unsigned int, 2>>(var);
```

Where `var` above is the size of the "first dimension". Now you can directly access `hashFunc[x][y]` where `x` is in range of `var` and `y` is zero or one.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Is there a reason for me to use vector and array instead of what AndreyT offered? (I do set the value of var at once and never change it)

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can go about this. Either have a class with a bare pointer or encapsulate it with `std::vector` and `std::array`. Below is a sample of two possible implementations which do exactly the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>

class TheClass {
public:
    typedef int TwoInts[2];
    TheClass(const std::size_t size) : m_size(size)
    {
        m_hashFunc = new TwoInts[m_size];
        if (m_hashFunc == NULL) throw std::runtime_error("Ran out of memory.");
    }
    virtual ~TheClass()
    {
        delete [] m_hashFunc;
    }

    inline       std::size_t size()                                               const { return m_size; }
    inline       int&        operator()(const std::size_t i, const std::size_t j)       { return m_hashFunc[i][j]; }
    inline const int&        operator()(const std::size_t i, const std::size_t j) const { return m_hashFunc[i][j]; }
private:
    std::size_t m_size;
    TwoInts* m_hashFunc;
};

class AnotherClass {
public:
    AnotherClass(const std::size_t size) : m_hashFunc(size)
    {
        // Nothing to do here.
    }

    // No destructor required.

    inline       std::size_t size()                                               const { return m_hashFunc.size(); }
    inline       int&        operator()(const std::size_t i, const std::size_t j)       { return m_hashFunc[i][j]; }
    inline const int&        operator()(const std::size_t i, const std::size_t j) const { return m_hashFunc[i][j]; }
private:
    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> m_hashFunc;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) return -1;
    const std::size_t runtimesize = static_cast<std::size_t>(atoll(argv[1]));
    const std::size_t i1 = rand() % runtimesize;
    const std::size_t i2 = rand() % runtimesize;
    TheClass instance1(runtimesize);
    AnotherClass instance2(runtimesize);
    instance1(i1,0) = instance2(i1,0) = 4;
    instance1(i2,1) = instance2(i2,1) = 2;
    std::cout << instance1(i1,0) << ' ' << instance2(i1,0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << instance1(i2,1) << ' ' << instance2(i2,1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << instance1.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << instance2.size() << std::endl;
    // ... etc
    return 0;
}
```